# how to listen for all active websockets messages in javascript

Tags: websocket, addeventlistener, message, ws

hey guys so i have this email provider called https://emailfake.com/channel6/ i want a script that will listen for all ws comming messages for already opened connections

```html
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://emailfake.com');


// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

note : a script that will work on console of devtools